# Pack and install Node package in offline mode with yarn

Tags: node.js, offline, yarnpkg

I try to add a package (not published) in my project in offline mode.

---

I configured the yarn-offline-mirror in the yarnrc of my project :

```
yarn-offline-mirror "./yarn-offline-mirror"
```

I modify manually the package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@xxx/yyy": "1.0.0",
 }
```

---

I packed my package :
yarn pack --filename @xxx/yyy@1.0.0

I moved manually the package @xxx/yyy@1.0.0 in the folder "yarn-offline-mirror" of my project.

---

I run in my project :

```
yarn install --offline
```

I obtain :

> error Couldn't find any versions for "@xxx/yyy"
>   that matches "1.0.0" in our cache (possible versions are
>   ""). This is usually caused by a missing entry in the
>   lockfile, running Yarn without the --offline flag may help fix this
>   issue.

---

If I publish and install my package @xxx/yyy@1.0.0 in my project (in online mode)  and after, I reinstall in offline mode with yarn-offline-mirror, it works.

But I want pack and add my package @xxx/yyy@1.0.0 in my project without publish  my package (in the case where I have no internet connection).

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure you have followed the [blog](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/) which contains all the steps.
I followed it as well, there is an important point it is not obvious.
The `yarn-offline-mirro` is based on `yarn.lock` file (which is auto-generated after you run `yarn install`). That is key relevant point in the procedure and was not well highlighted in the blog post.

Install your package as whatever other package in "online" mode with `yarn install` and you will see the packages `.tgz` are in your `[off-line-folder]`, then you can delete `[node_modules]` in your project folder eventually you can execute `yarn cache clean` or even move you offline, but NEVER delete the `yarn.lock`.
After that, `yarn install --offline` should work as expected.